# How to retrieve data from mysql database from what is the input on my textfield

Tags: user-interface

For example I have entered my pin to 123 in my text field I want that program to Show the balance, card number and account number of that certain pin

i used setters and getters to get the pin from the previous frame (login)

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*; 
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class Test extends JFrame 
{
  private static final Test sh1 = new Test();
public static Test getInstance()
{
    return sh1;
}
Container c;
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
ResultSetMetaData rm;
JTable tb;
JButton btnback = new JButton("Back");
JTextField pin = new JTextField("");

public void setUser(String user) {this.pin.setText(user);}
public String getUser() {return this.pin.getText();}

 public Test(){
 this.setTitle("Data");
 this.setSize(500,500);
 this.setLocation(800, 80);
 this.setBackground(Color.black);
 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 c=this.getContentPane();
 c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
 c.add(btnback);
 c.add(pin);
 stud();


}
 public void stud()
{
    Vector ColName = new Vector();
 Vector Data = new Vector();

    try{
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String db="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm";
        String user="root";
        String pass="";
        Class.forName(driver);
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(db,user,pass);
        st=con.createStatement();
           String pincodee = pin.getText().trim();
         String sqltb = "Select balance,cardnumber , accountnumber from accounts WHERE "
                 + "pincode = '"+pincodee+"' ";

            rs = st.executeQuery(sqltb);
            rm = rs.getMetaData();
            int col = rm.getColumnCount();
            for(int i = 1; i <= col; i++)
            {

                ColName.addElement(rm.getColumnName(i));
            }

            while(rs.next())
            {
                Vector row = new Vector(col);
                for(int i = 1; i <= col; i++)
                {
                    row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                    String s = rs.getString(2);

                       pin.setText(s);
                }
                Data.addElement(row);
            }


        }
     catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }

   tb = new JTable( Data, ColName);
   tb.repaint();
   JScrollPane sc = new JScrollPane(tb);
   sc.validate();
   c.add(sc);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test s = new Test();
    s.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a button which says 'Go!' or something like that and add an action listener to it that calls your stud() method.

look here for example..

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/278-how-add-actionlistener-jbutton-swing.html

Your code is not going to work either way, you need to rewrite a great deal of it but the ActionListener class is your friend if you want actions on the user interface to call logic code.